# Keeping only the top x number of bars in a Stacked barchart based on sum value via ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mrlfnh6e2ww1xwd/home.csv?dl=0

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(home.melt, 
           aes(x = reorder(home, value, FUN = sum), y = value, 
               fill=forcats::fct_rev(variable))) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.8) + coord_flip() +
      theme_minimal(base_size=10) +
      labs(title="Home time",
           subtitle="By matches",
           x="Home",
           y="time (minutes)",
           fill=" ")
```

This works fine, but I'd like to keep only the top 3 bars in terms of sum value.

Comment: Subset `home.melt` first. Data should be included in the question, so this question remains reproducible for others in the future. Use e.g. `dput`.

Comment: I personally prefer to use `ggplot` for plotting data. Data munging (applying functions (e.g. `sum`), subsetting) is done outside `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options for consideration:

**Option 1**. As per @PoGibas' comment, subset data first:

```
library(dplyr); library(data.table)

home.subset <- home %>%

  # get total for each ID
  group_by(home) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  mutate(total = a1+a2+a3+b1+b2+b3+b7) %>%

  # keep only top 3 ranks (including ties) & order by ID
  filter(rank(desc(total), ties.method = "min") <= 3) %>% 
  mutate(home = factor(home, levels = home[order(total)])) %>%
  select(-total) %>%

  # now reshape
  melt(id.vars = "home")

ggplot(home.subset, 
       aes(x = home, y = value, 
           fill=forcats::fct_rev(variable))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.8) + coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal(base_size=10) +
  labs(title="Home time",
       subtitle="By matches",
       x="Home",
       y="time (minutes)",
       fill=" ")
```

**Option 2**. Zoom in to selected part of plot (which I normally wouldn't do, but since you sorted the categorical variables along the axis already...):

```
library(data.table)

home.melt <- melt(home, id.vars = "home")

ggplot(home.melt, 
       aes(x = reorder(home, value, FUN = sum), y = value, 
           fill=forcats::fct_rev(variable))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) + 

  # zoom in to last 3 bars on the axis
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.5)) +
  coord_flip(xlim = c(length(unique(home.melt$home))-2,
                           length(unique(home.melt$home)))) +

  theme_minimal(base_size=10) +
  labs(title="Home time",
       subtitle="By matches",
       x="Home",
       y="time (minutes)",
       fill=" ")
```

[image: plot]

Data source (from OP's link, reproduced below for reference):

```
> dput(home)
structure(list(home = c("st", "Ln", "tg", "st", "Ln", "st", "Ln", 
"gg", "st", "st", "st", "Ln", "Ty", "st", "br", "br", "Ty", "br", 
"gg", "Ty", "br", "Mt", "br", "tg", "Ln", "br", "Tl", "gg", "Ar", 
"Tl", "st", "st", "gg", "br", "Ty", "Ar", "br"), a1 = c(54.75, 
52.75, 54, 24, 28, 33.5, 21, 16.75, 92.5, 25.75, 42.25, 10.25, 
0, 24.75, 0, 17.75, 0, 0.75, 0, 5.75, 30.5, 0, 9.5, 20.5, 3.25, 
0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6.25, 1.25, 0, 0.75, 0, 3.75, 0), a2 = c(33.75, 
65, 38.75, 34, 36.25, 38.75, 18.25, 40.25, 0, 13.25, 24, 17.25, 
9.5, 27.5, 19.75, 17.5, 0, 4.25, 10, 8, 0, 0, 14.5, 0, 6.5, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.25, 6.5, 1.5, 0, 0, 0.25), a3 = c(36, 50, 30.75, 
33.5, 22, 26.5, 34.75, 22.5, 0, 16.75, 16.5, 21.25, 21.25, 25.5, 
14.25, 20.25, 13.75, 0, 2.75, 6.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 10.5, 0, 
0, 9.5, 0, 3.75, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 2), b1 = c(42.5, 47.75, 27.5, 
32.75, 37.25, 25.75, 36, 12.25, 0, 12, 0, 28.5, 17.75, 0, 10, 
14.75, 8, 9.75, 2.25, 1.75, 0, 28.5, 0, 0, 0, 2.75, 0, 0, 10.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.75, 4.75, 5.25), b2 = c(49.25, 44, 41.75, 34.75, 
49.75, 34.75, 21.75, 15.5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11.25, 0, 29.25, 0, 8, 
11.5, 0, 4.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 11.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 3.5, 
0.5, 3.75), b3 = c(52, 34, 28.75, 40.5, 28.5, 30, 30.75, 16.5, 
7.25, 18.25, 0, 0, 18.25, 0, 0, 0, 8.5, 17, 12, 5.75, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 5.25, 0, 7.25, 6.5, 0, 6.5, 5.75, 3.25, 3.25, 1.5, 4.25, 2.25, 
0), b7 = c(70, 43.5, 54.5, 39, 34.25, 35, 36.5, 12.5, 0.25, 13.25, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.75, 0, 5.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.5, 
0, 0, 0.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("home", "a1", "a2", 
"a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-37L))
```

Comment: You can achieve the second while keeping the discrete axis by setting the appropriate limits. Try adding `scale_x_discrete(limits = tail(levels(reorder(home.melt$home, home.melt$value, FUN = sum)), 3))`. Also, you can use `geom_col()`.

Comment: Thanks, the first methods works fine. However, I found that if there is tie at the last spot (top 5, 10, etc.), then one of them gets omitted. Is there a way to include one additional bar in case there are ties?

Comment: @user709413 Have edited my solution to account for tied ranks.